# How the Poisson distribution is used in regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I am trying to intuitively understand the Poisson regressions, but I don't get:

1. why the increasing variance along with the mean is relevant?
2. how each of these three theoretical Poisson distributions was shown here, i.e. using each Y value as a mean=variance?

So far, my understanding is that for each Y a theoretical distribution is drawn, and then the best curve is fitted to maximize the cumulative probabilities (maximum likelihood?)

[image]

Comment: Remember that for $Y\sim Poisson(\lambda)$, $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\lambda$ and $Var (Y)= \lambda$. It’s not like a normal distribution where you get to choose whatever mean and variance you want.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking in number 2. Can you clarify?

Comment: In no. 2 I wanted to ask whether those distributions are drawn from Y values here or they are theoretical.

Comment: Presumably they're the fitted Poissons at those values of x but since you *don't say how that part of the plot was generated* - not even what you did to obtain it - we have no way to know for sure what it really is; there are other possibilities. We're not magical.

Answer (score 7):

> why the increasing variance along with the mean is relevant?

Remember that the variance of a Poisson random variable is equal to its mean.  If the mean increases, so too does the variance.

> how each of these three theoretical Poisson distributions was shown here, i.e. using each Y value as a mean=variance?

Regression is all about the *conditional distribution* of the outcome.  If you fix $x$ and observe $y$ a bunch of times, and then look at the histogram of those $y$, then that histogram should be Poisson.

Answer (score 5):

1. For $Y\sim Poisson(\lambda)$, $\mathbb E\big[Y\big] = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = \lambda$. If the mean of the conditional distribution increases, the variance of the conditional distribution must increase, too. If there is no such increase, too much increase, or too little increase, then Poisson would appear not to be the right conditional distribution. Negative binomial could be an alternative.
2. In your plot, it looks like $\hat y(1.75) = 2.5$, $\hat y(3) = 4.8$, and $\hat y(4.7) = 10$. That is, the conditional distributions are $\big(Y\vert X = 1.75\big) \sim Poisson(2.5)$,
   $\big(Y\vert X = 3\big) \sim Poisson(4.8)$,
   and $\big(Y\vert X = 4.7\big) \sim Poisson(10)$. The plots shows sideways plots of those distributions, positioned at the appropriate $x$-positions.

For that regression curve, you posit that $\log(\lambda_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i$, equivalent to $\lambda_i = \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i)$, and you find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, with the curvature explained by the logarithm. (Each $\lambda_i$ is the $\lambda$ parameter of some conditional Poisson distribution (conditional on your predictor variable, $x$).)

Comment: This plot appears to be on the natural scale.  The curvature is not necessarily quadratic, it might come from application of the inverse link.

Comment: @DemetriPananos You're right--edited.